# How do I make my application run in Full Trust mode - .NET 4.0 Console Application

Tags: security, .net-4.0, full-trust

We are having an issue with a command line (batch) application and full/partial trust.

Our previous release (version number 7.13.0.63) works fine, however, when we install the new version (7.13.0.249) we get a “That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.”

Exception:

```
Stack Trace (edited):
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance[T]()
   at <Company>.Service.<Product>.Proxy.Factories.ControllerProxyFactory.Create[T]()
   <Stack Trace that leads to creation of a WCF client> ...

Inner Exception:
An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.serviceModel/behaviors: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers. (C:\Program Files (x86)\InsuranceLine\ListLoader\InsuranceLine.ListLoader.Launcher.exe.Config line 53)
Stack Trace:
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecordsectionRecord, Object parentResult)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetSectionFromConfigurationManager(String sectionPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.AspNetEnvironment.UnsafeGetConfigurationSection(String sectionPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ConfigurationHelpers.UnsafeGetAssociatedSection(ContextInformation evalContext, String sectionPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupChannel(ContextInformation configurationContext, String configurationName, ContractDescription contract, EndpointAddress address, Boolean wildcard, Boolean useChannelElementKind, ServiceEndpoint& serviceEndpoint)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   <Stack Trace that determines the correct WCF factory to create>

Inner Exception:
That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ThrowSecurityException(RuntimeAssembly asm, PermissionSet granted, PermissionSet refused, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal rmh, SecurityAction action, Object demand, IPermission permThatFailed)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1.CreateNewSection(String name)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1.DeserializeElementCore(XmlReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceModelExtensionCollectionElement`1.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElementCollection.OnDeserializeUnrecognizedElement(String elementName, XmlReader reader)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement(XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
```

In regards to the process that we use to deploy our product, we use a MSI created through WiX. We perform the following steps:

- Uninstall the previous version of the product
- Copy the msi from a network share (same share for both versions, different subdirectory based on versions)
- Install the msi as an administrator

  - This installs to C:\Program Files (x86)

The only changes between the 2 versions are:

- The inclusion of an extra AppSettings item in the app.config file (myapp.exe.config) to specify a transaction timeout
- Changing a “using new TransactionScope()” to “using New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, timeoutValueReadFromAppSettingsAndStoredInLocalVariable)”

  - The creation of the WCF client is outside of this Transaction Scope.

Additional Information:

- The exception does not occur in any of our dev/staging/qa/pre production environments. It only happens on our production application server.
- We are in the process of rolling out Windows 7 to our organisation, so it is possible that enterprise policy has changed.
- The application targets the .Net Framework 4.0
- If we uninstall the new version, and reinstall the old version (including the copy from network share) the old version works fine still
- The machine being installed to is Windows Server 2008 R2
- The machine is a Virtual Machine that is hosted in a VMWare environment

Ideally I’d like to know a few things:

1. How to alter the assembly (or set permissions after install) so that it can run in a full trust mode
2. How to replicate the issue in dev/staging/QA environments

   - Explicitly "untrusting" the assembly might reproduce it, but I want to reproduce it in the same way as production so that when it is installed it is identified as untrusted, it seems to me that the way to do this would have something to do with “untrusting” the network share I copy the MSI from, or possibly “untrusting” the publisher information in the MSI/assembly.
3. How to configure the production application server/security policy so that future installs are fully trusted (Answering item 2 will most likely answer this)

Thanks

Comment: Added additional information that the server is a Virtual that is hosted in VMWare.

Comment: Did you find solution for this? I am running into similar issue. I want to run my application (EXE) with Full or High trust and I am also using WiX to generate installer?

Comment: Sorry Darshan, I didn't find a true solution. 2-3 days later the install of the new version worked fine (exact same MSI from same network location). However, no one will admit to having made any changes to the environment, and I have been unable to replicate the issue since.

Answer (score 1):

This is really quite odd given that the .NET 4.0 CLR does not apply CAS security policy by default, so you would actually have to make a some sort of (hopefully) deliberate change to get a locally installed command line application to be partially trusted.

Before trying to dig too deep for potential causes, could you please verify the following:

1. Does your app.config file contain a [NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253.aspx) element?
2. Is your application actually running under the 4.0 CLR on the problem machine?  (If you can't modify the source to output the value of Environment.Version before the exception is thrown, [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) should allow you to determine which CLR version(s) are running in your process.)

Comment: In answer to 1. our app does not have an NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy element. In answer to 2. I'll have to get back to you later as I don't have access to the production server (I'll have to log an infrastructure job to get them to run it and report the results to me). Thanks for the suggestion though.